# How to extract weather data from a html doc using linux string manipulation

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I need to extract these info from this [weather forecast site](http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/irvine-ca/92612/weather-forecast/337095), but I don't know how much about string manipulation in linux:

```
acm_RecentLocationsCarousel.push({name:"Irvine, CA", daypart:'day',
href:'/en/us/irvine-ca/92612/weather-forecast/337095',
icon:'http://vortex.accuweather.com/adc2010/images/icons-numbered/01-m.png',
bg:'su', temp:'57',  realfeel:'57',  text:'Sunny'});
```

I want to get the `name`, `realfeel`, and `text`. So I can do something like this on terminal:

`wget -q -O- $URL | awk...`

I will get something like this back:

`It is Sunny in Irvine with 57 degree`

Comment: The usual recommendation in this area is a tool such as [beautiful soup](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beautiful+soup), but if your scripting is just awk/sed/grep, you might consider using lynx or elinks to dump the text (no wget needed).

Comment: a first step: `sed "s/^.*({\(.*\)});/\1/;s/\([\"']\), */\1\n/g" file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with comments above, if you don't expect to be doing a lot of extracting data from websites, something like this can serve:

```
#!/bin/bash
  awk '{
  fullLine=$0
  Name=fullLine
  sub(/^.*name:"/, "", Name); sub(/".*$/,"", Name)
  text=fullLine
  sub(/^.*text:'"'"'/,"", text); sub(/'"'"'.*$/,"", text)
  realfeel=fullLine
  sub(/^.*realfeel:'"'"'/,"",realfeel) ; sub(/'"'"'.*$/,"", realfeel)
  #dbg print "#dbg:realfeel=" realfeel
  printf("It is %s in %s with %d degrees\n", text, Name, realfeel)
}' "$0"
```

can work for you.

For example, to match `text:'Sunny'` and strip away everything but `Sunny`, I am having to specify `text:'`, and because of shell quoting, I have to use the regexp `/^.*text:'"'"'/`, which, when quoting is stripped away and processed by awk, is left as `/^.*text:'/`.

Output:

```
It is Sunny in Irvine, CA with 57 degrees
```

---

You can put the above script in a file like `weather.sh`, "mark" it as executable  with

```
chmod 755 /full/path/to/weather.sh
```

and then call it like

```
/full/path/to/weather.sh /full/path/to/data/weather_Irving,Ca.dat
```

Ugly, but it gets this particular job done. Don't rely on this sort of technique to parse complicated HTML or XML!!!

IHTH

Comment: I actually use an API with json now instead of this HTML doc. Thanks